# Python 2.7 - Keep two working versions of package in memory

Tags: python, import, module, package, reload

Is it possible to do smth like that without breaking anything:

```
import some
some_copy = some
print some.version  # v1.0

# modify code and reload package
# ...
print some.version  # v1.1
print some_copy.version  # v1.0
```

So I want to have two different versions of module/package running simultaneously (in one process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have two scripts. The first, called some.py like this one

```
class some(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.version = '1.0'
```

and the other one, called wcode.py. Executing it

```
import some
some1 = some##.some()

raw_input("Waiting for you to change '1.0' into '1.1'.\nPress ENTER when done.")

reload(some)
some2 = some##.some()

print(some1().version)
print(some2().version)
```

prints

```
1.0
1.0
```

Why ? Simply because the imported definition of `some` is overriden. Which means that you may want to instantiate it so as to keep its methodes defined as in the first version class. As follows

```
import some
some1 = some.some()

raw_input("Waiting for you to change '1.0' into '1.1'.\nPress ENTER when done.")

reload(some)
some2 = some.some()

print(some1.version)
print(some2.version)
```

prints

```
1.0
1.1
```

So the answer is ***NO*** *conditionnally*, what you want to do is not possible whithout **instantiating your first version class** ***before*** **reloading the module**. As done above, actually. Note that why in the world you want to do this is beyond me. But you may have good reasons.

Comment: I am curious of this -1. I would be glad to know why since ***this works and adresses the question***.

Comment: but is it possible to do the same for packages? I've tried to reload packages and stuck to the modules cache, then tried to delete every module in a package from sys.modules, but it breaks first version of a package in memory.

why I want to do this:
my program looks like that: server and multiple bots (in different threads). Server receives a request from the social network (user sends a message to bot) and sends data to one of the bots. I wanna modify and hot reload those bots (no need to restart server). But in case of fail I think it will be great to restore prev. working version.

Comment: @user3092693. As said above, yes only if you instantiate packages sub-objects, so as to keep in memory their constructed versions, before reloading them.

Comment: I do that, but in fact, after loading second version of a package I got None instead of imported modules in first version of my bot. However, bot instance still exists.
It looks like https://pastebin.com/c2MSrHe0

Comment: @user3092693. Try this [https://pastebin.com/mjNv5Q9C](https://pastebin.com/mjNv5Q9C)

Comment: It doesn't work as is, but i managed to fix using https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bellbind/490613/raw/08db9769ff6f61deeef8cab37b8a2acb15073182/relimporter.py
Thank you.